# Deleting duplicates rows from sql database. Only using some colums

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I want to delete duplicate rows from my database which share some identical columns, but not all columns.
My code so far:

```
SELECT sfb_id, prs_id_201304, prs_id_201204, vorname, nachname, sex, gebdat, strasse, hausnummer, ort, plz, beg_dat, end_dat, quelle
INTO #duplicates
FROM [Recordlinkage].[dbo].[2012]
GROUP BY vorname, nachname, hausnummer, ort, plz
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

-- delete all rows that are duplicated
DELETE FROM [Recordlinkage].[dbo].[2012]
FROM [Recordlinkage].[dbo].[2012] o INNER JOIN #duplicates d
ON d.vorname= o.vorname and d.nachname=o.nachname and d.hausnummer=o.hausnummer and d.ort=o.ort and d.plz=o.plz

INSERT INTO [Recordlinkage].[dbo].[2012] (vorname, nachname, hausnummer, ort, plz)
SELECT sfb_id, prs_id_201304, prs_id_201204, vorname, nachname, sex, gebdat, strasse, hausnummer, ort, plz, beg_dat, end_dat, quelle
FROM #duplicates
```

I want only to delete duplicates which are identical in vorname, nachname, hausnummer, ort und plz. I testet it to only select this sub set of variables. It worked but I am missing the information in all other columns which where not selected prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: You can try this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnname ORDER BY columnname DESC) FROM tablename 
)
delete from CTE where RN>1
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DELETE
FROM (SELECT vorname, nachname, hausnummer, ort, plz,
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY vorname, nachname, hausnummer, ort, plz
                            ORDER BY sfb_id) as rnk
           FROM [Recordlinkage].[dbo].[2012]) a
WHERE a.rnk > 1
```